# Flash is freezing AVCaptureSession

Tags: iphone, ios, camera, avcapturesession

I have the following code to turn on the torch and flash:

```
                AVCaptureDevice *device = [AVCaptureDevice defaultDeviceWithMediaType:AVMediaTypeVideo];
            if ([device hasTorch]) {
                [self.session beginConfiguration];
                [device lockForConfiguration:nil];
                if(self.flashlightOn == YES)
                {
                    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOn];
                    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOn];
                    NSLog(@"TurnFlashOn");
                }
                else
                {
                    [device setTorchMode:AVCaptureTorchModeOff];
                    [device setFlashMode:AVCaptureFlashModeOff];
                    NSLog(@"TurnFlashOff");
                }

                [device unlockForConfiguration];
                [self.session commitConfiguration];
```

But if the code is called my session seems to freeze, if I remove the [device setTorchMode:] part everything works fine.
Does anybody knows whats happening here?

EDIT:
It only appears when running the app without IDE -> on its own

Comment: any solution, I am stuck in same kind of problem?

Answer (score 3):

I was having the same kind of problem with swapping between the front and back cameras.  It would work the first time I used the device, then freeze on "commitConfiguration" every time after that.  It would seem that the proper sequence is:

```
            [self.session beginConfiguration];
            [device lockForConfiguration:nil];

            //*** Do your session configuration stuff here

            [device unlockForConfiguration];
            [self.session commitConfiguration];

            //*** And this is what fixed the problem:
            self.session startRunning];
```

Hope this does the trick for you!